# Get a list of installed Mini Filter driver in windows

Tags: c++, delphi, driver, minifilter

I want to get a list of installed Mini-Filter driver in MS Windows but I don't know how I can do it.

My programming language is Delphi (I can also use C or C++) can any one help me to do this ?

Comment: There is a kernel API function named `FltEnumerateFilters` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542064(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In the normal WinAPI you could probably try the registry, e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FltMgr\Enum`

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff : Is it possible to use this API function ( FltEnumerateFilters ) in user-land application ?? or I've to use this in kernel-land ?

Comment: No, FltEnumerateFilters is not available in "user-land".

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff : Thanks for your advise. i think the registry base way isn't very trusty! is it ??

Comment: @BehroozAbbassi, why would the registry not work, Windows itself depends on that info, I'd say its pretty trustworthy.

Comment: @Johan , you're right but [malware](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMalware&ei=ZBRVUsDFHqrg4QTfhICIAg&usg=AFQjCNGz8uxWJBad-7_IWsMZ8yjKcxNNuQ&sig2=HH9c5kR3eC9yrRHeIb8FYQ) able to modify the registry easily! and its not good for me.

Comment: Your argument does not make sense. Windows itself follows the registry. By definition, if your mini driver is listed in the reg. it's a mini driver. The registry defines which files are mini drivers nothing else. So by definition the registry is correct. Whether a mini driver is malware or not is irrelevant. If malware is in there the other method would list it as a mini driver as well. Just because a mini driver happens to be malware does not make it any less of a mini driver, it's just one that works against you rather than for you.

Comment: @Johan is right. If you machine is so compromised that you have malware installed in HKLM, that machine needs to be wiped and reinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the (for example) following API functions in user-land for get a list of installed Mini-Filter driver in MS Windows :-) .

```
FilterFindFirst
FilterFindNext
```

for more in formation see this link :
[**Minifilter User-Mode Application Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The following code enumerates the items using the registry:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Registry;

procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  count: integer;
  i: integer;
  Item: string;
  AllOK: boolean;
begin
  Reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    Reg.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; //Note must set the base first.
    //Then open rest of the subtree underneigh.
    AllOK:= Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FltMgr\Enum');
    if (AllOK) then begin
      count:= Reg.ReadInteger('Count');
      for i:= 0 to count - 1 do begin
        Item:= Reg.ReadString(IntToStr(i));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Item);
      end; {for}
    end else {not(AllOK)} begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FltMgr\Enum does not exist');
      exit;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The entries returned look like: `Root\LEGACY_FLTMGR\0000`
The `Root` is a reference to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Root`.
For the above entry you can thus get all info from: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Root\LEGACY_FLTMGR\0000`.

This entry look like this:

[image]

Comment: +You can compare your results with `fltmc filters` (from an elevated cmd prompt).

Answer (score 2):

The best method to enumerate all mini filter drivers is via a command line of [fltmc](https://ss64.com/nt/fltmc.html).
Make sure you open CMD as Administrator and then just type 'fltmc'.
Then, since you are looking for a way to do so programmatically, just use [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) to call this command from your program. This is shown in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564594/c-executing-cmd-commands). 
The proper way of doing so would be:

```
ShellExecute( NULL, "open",
    "cmd.exe",
    "fltmc.exe",
    NULL,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

[image]